# Is there any other way to get "files.associations" in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running VS Code version 1.33.1 (1.33.1)

In my `settings.json` file I have:

```
"files.associations": { // breaks node, express auto complete
   "*.js": "javascriptreact",
  },
```

I'd like to have all my `.js` files default to `JavaScript React`(I use it because sometimes the react file will be set to BabelJavaScript which breaks the jsx) But this breaks some nifty extensions (see above to see the cause of my lamentations).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer this as others might find it useful:

I just removed this explicit notation as vs code seems to auto detect a file ending with `.js`, anyway, and because of my [prettier set up](https://twitter.com/wesbos/status/1105552781501497345?lang=en). I discovered I didn't need it. Thanks Wes Bos! Also by removing it, my [theme](https://github.com/sdras/night-owl-vscode-theme)—*NightOwl* is working better! i.e. Much richer attribute and keyword identification!

*UPDATE 9-23-19*

I'd like to add the following:

Sometimes it takes time to get to know what is going on with a tool (in this case an extension and editor) and take a step back and think about the problem.

Coincidently I had a problem with my `.jsx` not playing nice with the aforementioned `prettier`. Then it dawned on me. My original problem was my thinking how the extensions should be applied in such a universal matter to all `.js` extensions.

Simply, the extensions in question were targeting vanilla `javascript` in this case 
they were Node and express autocompletes. And I believe because the popular thinking that React is just JavaScript. I felt why wouldn't they work on the back end just because I had those file types preset to be recognized as JavaScriptReact,  if I had that universal setting above?

Truth is for sake of the extensions, one should just be explicit. Especially if you want better recognition of all the great benefits you get from them. And it just makes sense why would you need Node or Express autocompletes on your front end?

This was my new solution:

```
 "files.associations": {
  ".gitignore": "shellscript",
   "['*.js.liquid', '*.js']": "javascript",
   "['*.jsx']": "javascriptreact"
 },
```